# Built-in events are not being listened in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am firing some built-in events from my controller. But no events are being (listened and) responded. I have followed [this doc](https://github.com/laravel/docs/blob/8.x/passwords.md#handling-the-form-submission-1) to setup password reset functionality, but the `\Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset` event is not working. My expectation is that it should send the confirmation email. Below are the codes I have:

**routes/web.php:**

```php
//...
Route::get('/reset-password/{token}', [AuthController::class, 'reset'])->middleware('guest')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('/reset-password', [AuthController::class, 'shiny'])->middleware('guest')->name('password.update');
```

**app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php:**

```php
//...
public function reset(string $token): View
{
    return view('auth/password/reset', ['token' => $token]);
}

public function shiny(ResetUserRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $status = Password::reset(
        $request->only('email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'),
        function ($user, $password) use ($request) {
            $user->forceFill(['password' => $password])->save();
            if (!empty($user->getRememberToken())) {
                $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));
            }
            event(new PasswordReset($user)); // not working
        }
    );
    if ($status !== Password::PASSWORD_RESET) {
        return back()->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
    }
    return redirect()->route('auth.signin')->with('status', __($status));
}
```

But only one event is being responded: `\Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered`. No other event is being responded. I suspect this is happening because no listeners are provided for other events (except for that one) in `\App\Providers\EventServiceProvider` provider. This is what I got when I scaffolded the project:

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
        // no more listeners for other types of events
        // could this be the reason?
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I'm basically a JS developer, so this all seems complicated to me. Client specifically asked me to do it using Laravel, so that's the problem. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. no more listeners for other types of events. You should add desired listeners.
2. could this be the reason? YES.

It would be something like:

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset; // Pay attention to the namespace 
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
        PasswordReset::class => [
            //Listiners that you need to be called after triggering the PasswordReset event.
        ]

    ];
```

Comment: If this is the case, why the doc has no guideline that I should register listener before firing "built-in" events? Almost everything is pre-configured out-of-the-box, except these listeners? Do you know where I can get reference of the listeners? I mean which listener should I register for `PasswordReset` event and so on?

Comment: @msrumon you write your own listeners to do what you want, the only reason that event is fired is so you can add a listener if you want to